# Visual Studio OneClick publish from command line isn't generating proper directory structure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, excel-2007, oneclick

**Problem**
Trying to publish an Excel 2007 Addin from the command line produces unexpected directory names/directory structure when trying to set the PublishDir property.

**What I'm doing**
I'm trying to publish an Excel 2007 addin via the command line.  I have set everything up in the project and when I publish it from Visual Studio everything works perfectly.  I can also publish from the commandline with the following and it also works perfectly:

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:Configuration=release
```

However, as soon as I add the PublishDir property then things go all batty:

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:Configuration=release;PublishDir="C:\ExcelAddin\Publish"
```

When I either publish from Visual Studio or **do not** specify PublishDir then the files are put into a directory and everything looks like this:

[image: This is the expected (and working) file structure]

When I specify PublishDir="C:\ExcelAddin\Publish" then this is what C:\ExcelAddin looks like.
[image: This is the unexpected (and not working) file structure]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying the `PublishDir` property, you need to include the trailing `\`. If the trailing back slash isn't present, then the directories are smashed together and nothing seems to work correctly. I believe this  should work:

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:Configuration=release;PublishDir="C:\ExcelAddin\Publish\"
```

I found a reference to this while looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff624126.aspx